# How to deploy a project developed inJDK 16 java swing source code

Tags: mysql

I want to deploy java swing source code and a message appears like: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript. Hence, I need your help to excuse the source code.

I tried to package as EXE, I expected to execute and an error appeared.

Comment: Are you going to be storing the data in Rows and Columns or do you want to do JSON objects?  If it is the former you are on the right track, if it is the latter, you might lookinto MongoDB as a MUCH better solution for that type of data.  Not that MySQL can't do it, its just still getting patches to attempt to handle them, so keep that in mind.